# An regex using Groovy or Java to remove line-height

Tags: java, regex

I would like to create a regular expression to remove the line-height of a style, can be the following standards:

```
<p align="justify" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; font-weight: normal; line-height: 100%; text-decoration: none">
```

Or that:

```
<p align="justify" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; font-weight: normal; line-height: 100%">
```

the property can end with " or ; and may have any value.

Comment: Try a proper html parser because http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/995891 (or if you dare `htmlString.replaceAll("line-height:\\s*\\d+\\%;?", "")`

Comment: I try to create something like: `line-height:[^\"]+\"|line-height:[^;]+;` Look that: [sample](http://regexr.com/3dksf) but select a text-decoration.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
const removeLineHeightTag = (text: string) => {
  const regex = /(line-height: ((\d).)*(;)*)/g;
  try {
    return `${text.replace(regex, '')}`;
  } catch (e) {
    return text;
  }
};

let yourText = '...' // change to your text
yourText = removeLineHeightTag(yourText)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex: `(line-height:[\d\s]+%;?)`. To replace it, do the following.

```
yourString.replaceAll("(line-height:[\\d\\s]+%;?)", "");
```